# SQL WHERE Clause for x1="a" or z<>Blank but also not = to 'F'

Tags: sql, vb.net, where-clause

I’m struggling very badly with a multi what if WHERE clause… 
I am creating a dynamic SQL statement to retrieve data from PSQL database.

The SQL Dynamic Statement goes like this:

P1 = (Project #) Project code to include in the results
P2 = (Dept) Department ID to Exclude from the results
P3 = (ID) Control ID to Exclude from the results related to the P2 Department above

So, after the user inputs the values, they click an [Export] button that runs the code below.  But sql1 (my SQL statement WHERE variable) needs to be used to return all data for the flowing conditions:

Note: x1, x2, x3 are static values, and are not entered by the user

1)  All records that have: FieldA = P1 AND FieldB = Null AND (FieldC <> ’x1’ OR FieldC <> ’x2’ OR FieldC <> ’x3’)

2)  All records that have: FieldA = P1 AND (FieldB<>BLANK AND FieldB<>P2 AND FieldC<>P3)

It’s the second one above I’m having problems with:

I need all records that have (FieldA = P1 and FieldB = BLANK) BUT must exclude ALL records when FieldA = P1 and FieldB = P2 and FieldC = P3

Comment: have you tried: `(FieldA = P1 and FieldB = BLANK) AND NOT (FieldA = P1 and FieldB = P2 and FieldC = P3)`. You need to determine what BLANK is exactly. Probably you mean `(FieldA = P1 and FieldB IS NULL)`. Not quite sure yet

Comment: No.. But I will try and and let you know.  The "Blank' is Null.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use AND NOT.... Worked but also led me further in to another problem with my SQL statement.  At first I still didn't get the data results I expected, until I used a combination of the AND NOT and many more parenthesis to further segregate and chain together parts of the WHERE clause. This along with the AND NOT solved my issue!  Thanks